# Working of INET_NTOA

Tags: mysql, database, ip-address

Anyone know how the MySql INET_NTOA() is converting the integer value back to IP address format? I would like to know how the calculation is performed internally to convert the IP to its original internet standard dotted-decimal format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It decomposes an integer into four bytes using network [byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (big endian):

```
167773449 => A0 00 05 09
```

It then joins those bytes together with a dot in between:

```
10.0.5.9
```

Comment: How you converted 167773449 to A0 00 05 09? Can you please explain the manual calculation involved?

Comment: @VishnuY I grabbed my Casio and converted it :) typical decimal -> hexadecimal conversion.

Comment: But the corresponding value I got is A000509.

Comment: @VishnuY isn't that the same thing? the only difference is the grouping :)

Answer (score 0):

Writing 16777343 in Binary:
1 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1111 
Start grouping the bits (in groups of 8 to form a byte) starting from the LSB:
[1] [0000 0000] [0000 0000] [0111 1111]
And now writing in decimal in little endian form(Least significant byte first):
127.0.0.1
This can be verified by using : 
struct sockaddr_in antelope;
inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &antelope.sin_addr); // store IP in antelope
printf("%lld\n",antelope.sin_addr.s_addr);   //prints 16777343
printf("%s\n",inet_ntoa(antelope.sin_addr));   //prints 127.0.0.1

I hope it helps.